# Python: Index Error: sequence subscript is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to implement a word Chain game; it is a word game where players take turns saying words that start with the last letter of the previous word.

This is my code, and I keep getting an index error on line 9. Can anyone please help. Thanks

This is for Python 3:

```py
x = input('Word: ')
xx = 'sample'

while x and xx:
    if x == '':
        break
    xx = input('Word: ')
    if xx == '':
        break 
    while xx[0] != x[-1]:
        print('Invalid word')
        xx = input('Word: ')
    x = input('Word: ')
    if x == '':
        break
    while x[0] != xx[-1]:
        print('Invalid word')
        x = input('Word: ')
```

Here is the criteria

Word Chain is word game where players take turns saying words that start with the last letter of the previous word. You might have played this game on long car trips.

Write a program to help you play word chain. Your program should read in words until a blank line is entered. It should print out Invalid word if a word is not a valid play. Your program should work for upper case and lower case words.

​
Notice that the word mandarin is rejected because it doesn't start with the letter e from the previous word: orange. The next word still needs to start with the letter e (from orange), rather than n (from the end of the invalid word, mandarin).

Here is another example:

```
Word: tomato
Word: okra
Word: asparagus
Word: seaweed
Word: cake
Invalid word
Word: dried apricots
Word: cake
Invalid word
Word:
```

​
Here's one last example. Don't forget it should work regardless of case!

```
Word: Australia
Word: Antartic
Word: Canada
Word: England
Invalid word
Word: Denmark
Invalid word
Word:
```

​
You will always read in at least two words.

Please help if you can thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code here?

Comment: trying to complete a task to make a word chain game

Comment: Quote"Write a program to help you play word chain. Your program should read in words until a blank line is entered. It should print out Invalid word if a word is not a valid play. Your program should work for upper case and lower case words"

Comment: Also I realised line 13 has an index error as well

Comment: What is a `valid play`? How is it defined?

Comment: `input` whill handle digits, not string. Consider `raw_input` instead

Comment: And use a 4 space indentation is (by experience) the best to avoid messing code up.

Comment: @nicolallias That is not correct, `raw_input()` does not even work for `python3`.

Comment: @SuperKogito indeed https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html my bad :)

Comment: This is valid play:Word Chain is word game where players take turns saying words that start with the last letter of the previous word. You might have played this game on long car trips.

Comment: This is directly from the task

Comment: You should have included that in your question. Please next time, keep it mind to do it. Good luck :)

Comment: My answer should cover all the conditions, check my answer below @KendrickBUI

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include your condition in the `while` loop and simply your whole code like the following:

```py
word     = "elaborate"
old_word = 'sample'

while word != '' and old_word != '':
    old_word = word
    word = input('Word: ')

    if word[0].upper() != old_word[-1].upper():
        print('Invalid word')
        word = input('Word: ')
```

Comment: What test inputs you gave in?

Comment: I ran it through the tester and it said this: Testing the first example from the question. Your submission raised an exception of type IndexError. This occurred on line 8 of your submission.

Comment: Also, if you get the word wrong, the incorrect word is not the new word as in your code.

Comment: The system gave the random inputs

Comment: In that case you have to debug it on your own. I ran  some manual tests and it seemed to be okay.

Comment: Check if my answer below makes sense @KendrickBUI, it should check all the conditions you require!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, check the comments in the code! You would need to check if the word you have entered is of length > 1, and also keep track of the last good word!

```
old_word = 'sample'
word = input('Start the chain game, the first word is sample: ')

last_good_word = word
invalid_flag = False

#While the word is not empty
while word != '':

    #If the last word was invalid, use the last good word, else get the latest word
    if invalid_flag:
        old_word = last_good_word
    else:
        old_word = word

    #We get the new word
    word = input('Enter the next word: ')

    #Check if the new word is not a blank string
    if len(word) > 1:
        #If word chain is not met, tell that it is invalid, and set the invalid flag to True
        if word[0].upper() != old_word[-1].upper():
            print('Invalid word')
            invalid_flag = True
            last_good_word = old_word
        #Else set the invalid flag to False
        else:
            invalid_flag = False
```

Outputs will look like

```
Start the chain game, the first word is sample: echo
Enter the next word: open
Enter the next word: note
Enter the next word: even
Enter the next word: 

Start the chain game, the first word is sample: echo
Enter the next word: open
Enter the next word: yellow
Invalid word
Enter the next word: mellow
Invalid word
Enter the next word: note
Enter the next word: even
Enter the next word: yellow
Invalid word
Enter the next word: mellow
Invalid word
Enter the next word: never
Enter the next word: river
Enter the next word:
```